# github: how to record merge conflicts

Tags: git, github, git-remote

I have one branch `local_branch` and I merged into it from a new remote. Now there is a plenty of merge conflicts that I need to resolve. After solving them I need the resolution of the conflicts to propagate somehow to local `master` branch (by issuing pull request) instead of resolving them over between `master` and `local_branch`.

Whats best way to achieve that?

I don't want to directly merge the new remote into `master` because I want to issue a `git pull request` for the old remote for my colleagues to see which and how conflicts were resolved.

Just to clarify:

1. `new_remote branch` -> `local_branch` (from old remote)
2. Resolve merge conflicts
3. Pull request to merge to `master` (how to avoid second resolution of the very same conflicts?). `master` is pretty close to the `local_branch`, so between them there are no issues (before new remote merge)

Comment: Presumably there will be *different* conflicts between your branch and master, otherwise you should've already resolved them as part of your current task. If you need to perform a pull request towards master, the proper procedure is to merge master into your branch first, resolve any conflicts, and then issue the pull request.

Comment: I already merged master (old remote) before doing merge from the new remote

Comment: I don't want to resolve all conflicts twice

Comment: Do you even get conflicts? When you resolve them, the resolution is recorded as part of the merge conflict. Unless there are _different_ conflicts between your branch and master, there will be none to resolve. And if there are different conflicts, you must resolve them, because you have never resolved them before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge `master` into `local_branch`, resolve the conflicts, then push. This should be your normal process: update your branch, then push.

If `master` and `new_remote_branch` are similar you should not have to resolve the same conflicts twice; Git merging compares only the tips of each branch, not the histories. You may have different conflicts.

Try it. If it goes really wrong you can always abort the merge: `git merge --abort`

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding smth, but 'if master and new_remote_branch are similar ' - it is very false. Master is on old remote, and master and new remote branch are very different. So, after I merge the new remote changes into local branch, if I pull from master now, wouldn't I need to resolve the very same conflicts again?

Comment: @NikitaVlasenko "*after I merge the new remote changes into local branch*" I thought you had already done this. Are you saying you'll do it again? Perhaps you should tell us the full situation and why you're pulling from one remote but pushing to another. And, again, *just try the merge*.

Comment: Yes, of course, its already done and there is a plenty of merge conflicts. Ok, just trying not to do the same work twice. I will resolve conflicts soon, and then will try to issue PR to masters branch and will see. In my understanding though I would need to resolve conflicts the second time this way.

Comment: @NikitaVlasenko By first merging new_remote_branch into local_branch and then merging local_branch into master you are, effectively, merging new_remote_branch into master while also merging local_branch into master. I would suggest doing these as two separate steps. 1) merge new_remote_branch into master and get that out of the way, 2) update local_branch by merging master into local_branch, and finally 3) merge local_branch into master. Yes, this means you'll have to resolve the conflicts again, but it will be a simpler process. This is my best guess without knowing the full situation.

Comment: @NikitaVlasenko For the future, look into [`git-rerere`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere). I've never had to use it myself, but it seems to be what you're looking for.